# Cannot get back the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect to action and get a new view (a new page) with no success. While debugging,  I'm reaching the controller but not getting the view (the page URL is not changed).

With Fiddler I see that the page returns the right view result but in the browser the URL is not changed!

When shopping cart is empty, I would like to redirect to a new page a display the error message.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder(DeliveryDetails deliveryDetails)
    {           
        if (UserCart.IsEmpty)
        {

            TempData["errorMsg"] = "Error: Cart is empty";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
        }
        else
        {
             // do something..
        }


     }
```

**ErrorController:**

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**ErrorController View:**

```
  @TempData["errorMsg"]
```

Any suggestions on what is going on ?

Comment: You edited your question, so not sure if my answer is correct (deleted it).

Comment: did you try to use a strong ViewModel and sent a clean/new viewmodel in your RedirectToAction ?

Comment: @ElYusubov You can't do that unfortunately. If the url not changing is the problem.. he should probably trying adding `[HttpGet]` on `Index`. Doubtful it'd make a difference.

Comment: *While debugging, I'm reaching the controller but not getting the view* - Which controller/action method? The Place order, or the index?
Just a guess but I suspect UserCart.IsEmpty returns false

Comment: @Eyal, i hope you have in place a controller named ErrorController and a view named Index in that controller. If not, you should get an error.

Comment: Sorry, It was js problem: event.isDefaultPrevented()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a js problem:
event.isDefaultPrevented()

Answer (score 0):

Is your 'ErrorController View:' should be named Index.cshtml? If it is not it should be.